# Instance with two NIC: how to explicitly choose which it will use as a default gateway

Tags: networking, openstack, gateway

I'm using openstack liberty.

I have the following network environment:
two networks A and B
network A has a router with external connection
network B has a router without external connection

When I launch a vm in both of those networks I need it to have the default gateway to be pointing to network A, where the external router is.
I tried lauching 5 vms through horizon and gateway assign seems to be random: 3 vms got gateway in network B, 2 vms in network A.

Does openstack have any options to configure it? Modifying the gateway by hand after it launches is not an option.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions only, and as such, asking about configuring a network is off topic.

Comment: This would probably do better on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

Network B should not be advertising a default gateway.

When you create a subnet in OpenStack, you have the option of specifying an explicit default gateway, as in:

```
neutron subnet-create mynetwork 10.0.0.0/24 --gateway 10.0.0.1
```

But you can also create a subnet that does not have a gateway address:

```
neutron subnet-create mynetwork 10.0.0.0/24 --no-gateway
```

If you create a network like this, the DHCP server created by Neutron to manage this network will not offer a default gateway as part of the DHCP lease, so your instances will only have a single default gateway via Network A.